# Cannot add foreign key with WordPress wp_posts table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, foreign-keys

I'm trying to add a new table which has a relation with {wp_posts} table, This code is working properly in localhost and it passes all tests but it failed on server database and generates [**Cannot add foreign key constraint**].

The [post_id] field is exactly like {wp_posts->ID} field .. I don't know what I missed.

```
global $wpdb;
$charset_collate = $wpdb->collate;

$tbl_my_users = $wpdb->prefix . '_TABLE_NAME';

dbDelta( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$tbl_my_users} (
            user_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
            post_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
            name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
            email TINYTEXT NULL,
            INDEX (name),
            PRIMARY KEY  (user_id),
            CONSTRAINT Constr_Unique_UserID UNIQUE( user_id ),
            CONSTRAINT Constr_Unique_PostID UNIQUE( post_id ),
            CONSTRAINT Constr_Unique_User UNIQUE( name ),
            CONSTRAINT Constr_My_Users 
                FOREIGN KEY FK_My_Users (post_id) REFERENCES {$wpdb->posts} (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ) COLLATE {$charset_collate}" );
```

Comment: At least write down why you down vote to understand .. You're really helpless. I didn't ask a hard question and get an answer in this website. You just need easy questions .. Right??

Answer (score 3):

old question but i face this problem now.

the issue is when we want to set relation we need to match the column type, collation and the engine.

wp_posts ID : `bigint(20) UNSIGNED`

your table post_id: `bigint(20) UNSIGNED`

this is match, but you have problem with `ENGINE`.

example : the old table is written as `innodb` but your MYSQL default engine is set as `MYISAM`. so you without define ENGINE type, you will create `MYISAM` table instead `InnoDB` which not support relationship/foreign key. Note: old mysql version using `MYISAM` as default engine, not `InnoDB`

In my problem:

wp_posts ID: bigint(20) UNSIGNED InnoDB

my table post_id: bigint(20) InnoDB

the engine and type is match, but i got the eror. Because i forgot to set attribute `UNSIGNED`. when i set the same attribute, all works perfectly.

Note: don't forget about `collation` when using string type like `varchar, char`, etc

i hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

try this bewlo query

```
  global $wpdb;
$charset_collate = $wpdb->collate;

$tbl_my_users = $wpdb->prefix . '_TABLE_NAME';

dbDelta("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  ".$tbl_my_users."  (
            user_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
            post_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
            name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
            email TINYTEXT NULL,
            INDEX (name),
            PRIMARY KEY  (user_id),
            CONSTRAINT Constr_Unique_UserID UNIQUE( user_id ),
            CONSTRAINT Constr_Unique_PostID UNIQUE( post_id ),
            CONSTRAINT Constr_Unique_User UNIQUE( name ),
            CONSTRAINT Constr_My_Users 
                FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES ".$wpdb->prefix."posts (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ) COLLATE SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci" );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, But I figured out the problem but I cannot solve it, I discovered that I should write the engine when creating the new table but it should equal the wp_posts table's engine.

So now I need to write [ ENGINE = old table engine ] .. I don't why it failed without write ENGINE keyword?